# Is there any library in flutter ,that can scan details of other applications in the device?

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to build a project in which we will create a report according to screen time of all the applications present in the device ,is there any suitable library present for flutter that can helps us out .
(if not library then any possible way to reach our need)

Comment: Note that Google does not want apps to get information about which other apps the user has installed (of which your usecase is an extension). See https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779#zippy=

Comment: You can do it by PackageManager in Java with permission.